# Inaccessible external hard drive

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive

I have a 2TB external hard drive I've had connected to my router for the past 2 years.  Recently, I noticed I wasn't able to access files on it.  However Windows did show that it was successfully on the network.  I restarted the router, the drive itself and was unable to see the contents of the drive.  It just continued to show "This folder is empty" when I opened it.

I took it off the network and plugged it directly into my Windows 10 computer one of 2 things is happening:

- It's recognizing this is the same drive from the network and thus not considering it a local/removable disk
- The drive is shot and it's not even registering when I connect it to my PC.

[image]

What steps can I take to verify the drive integrity?

Disk 3 is the drive in question

[image]

Comment: @Webnet - Provide a screenshot from Disk Management which shows if the disk is actually connected to the system or not.

Comment: @Ramhound - Great idea!  Done

Comment: You don't have a 2 TB disk connected to your system it's not even showing up at all which means the drive isn't even initializing at this point

Comment: The figure shows that Disk 3 has three partitions: 259 MB, 63 MB and 1862.70 GB.  If we assume that these are actually the binary-flavored numbers 259 MiB, 63 MiB and 1862.70 GiB, that adds up to 259 × 1024² + 63 × 1024² + 1862.70 × 1024³ = 271581184 + 66060288 + 2000058895564 = 2000396537036 = 2.0004 TB.

Comment: @Scott - Yes, the external drive is 2TB...

Answer (score 1):

Because you're saying

> It's recognizing this is the same drive from the network and thus not considering it a local/removable disk

I'm not sure if Windows is really seeing it or looking for it or not. Changing the windows network drive settings might help, and looking at a "windows hardware log" might help...

But I'm much more familiar with **linux** so I'd try booting a **live linux** (Mint, Ubuntu, Debian, etc) and once it's booted and running:

1. then plug in the USB hard drive
2. watch for changes in `lsblk` and `dmesg` &/or the `/var/log/syslog` file

   - If nothing shows up in `dmesg` or `/var/log/syslog` , that's very bad. The drive, or at least the USB adapter, appears to be dead. Trying [Ratwrangler's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1249818/307834) to plug the drive directly into a sata port is a decent next step (unless it's under warranty or exchangeable).

If several lines mentioning "usb" show up, then it's not completely dead. Look for a new device in `lsblk`. Drives are often named `/dev/sdX` [X being a letter in a-z] and partitions are a number, like `/dev/sdX1`

Mounting a partition should be a one-click operation with most file managers, or using `gnome-disk-utility` (aka "Disks") or in a terminal (read-only with the `-o ro` flag):

```
sudo mkdir -vp /media/X1
sudo mount -v -o ro /dev/sdX1 /media/X1
```

If all your files are there, then it's not the drive's problem. If only a few files are there, you could try to recover the missing files with a program like `testdisk` / `photorec`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have a linux machine so I'm not able to test this out.

Comment: If you've got a desktop or laptop that can run Windows, then you should be able to run linux too. Just need a USB or DVD with a live iso on it. A web search for [how to make a linux live usb on windows](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+make+a+linux+live+usb+on+windows&t=h_&ia=web) should have lots of options. https://www.pendrivelinux.com/ worked great for me (years ago when I last ran windows only)

Comment: While you're right, I can run Linux I'm looking for a Windows solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen with more than one external hard drive.  I assume when you connected it to the computer, you used it as an USB drive.  If you can open the external drive case, remove the drive, and attach it as a local SATA drive, you will probably find that all your data is there.  In all of my cases, the SATA to USB circuitry failed.  It would respond as an external drive, but would only pretend to read the hard drive.